# MudTextField sends HTTP request at every keystroke

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I use MudTextField for a login form. Whenever a user types something into the text field the application sends the current state to the server.

Example:

```
<MudTextField Label="Username" Class="mt-3" @bind-Value="user.username" />
```

It should only send the state when a user klicks on the login button.

Any ideas on how to disable it?

Thank you.

EDIT: Added more information for clarification.

[Pic related is the output from the network panel with long-polling enabled as a transport mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaia4.png)

This only happens when using a MudTextField component. Using a custom component with a HTML input field and vanilla razor two-way binding will not display the same behavior.

E.g:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" @bind="@user.username" placeholder="name@example.com">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
</div>
```

After browsing the MudBlazor website for information it seems that the `Immidiate` attribute would be the right option for it but I can't make it work.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. You should provide minimum code that handles your login logic. I got the same logic you provided in my login form and it works fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.